# Event listeners for jQuery's UI tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tabs

Are there event listeners available for jQuery UI's tabs widget?

I'm wanting to change the background colour on a web page depending on what tab index is currently active. So something like this (pseudo code):

```
$('.tabs').addEventListener(index, changeBackgroundImage);

function changeBackgroundImage(index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 1:
            $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/1.jpg');
        break;
        case 2:
            $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/2.jpg');
        break;
        case 3:
            $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/3.jpg');
        break;
        default:
            $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/default.jpg');
        break;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use tabsshow event, Index will be start from 0.

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { 
  switch (ui.index){
    case 0: 
        $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/1.jpg');
        break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 17):

it seems the old's version's of jquery ui don't support select event anymore.

This code will work with new versions:

```
$('.selector').tabs({
                    activate: function(event ,ui){
                        //console.log(event);
                        console.log(ui.newTab.index());
                    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Use tabsactivate event

```
$('#tabs').on('tabsactivate', function(event, ui) {
    var newIndex = ui.newTab.index();
    console.log('Switched to tab '+newIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ under "Events"

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/g7Q2L/ (I used embedded values and not the index to make the markup less coupled with the code)

Check the docs, you can `.bind( "tabsselect", function(){})` *or* when you initiate tabs add a `select` property to the initiliasing object like in my jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

the Tabs plugin have a 'show' event which is fired whenever a tab is shown.

check the events in documentation > http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/